# input tag to get file path

Tags: html, css

I've observed that the selected file path is being displayed  on Internet explorer and same does not appear in any other browser as shown below,

[image]

```
<li>Left File : <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /></li><li><br></li>
<li>Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /></li><li><br></li>
<li>Config File : <input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /></li><li><br></li>
```

So how do I get the path like in IE in chrome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701017/how-to-get-full-path-using-jquery-of-a-uploaded-file-when-use-input-type-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security concerns modern browsers such as Chrome and Firefox do not provide you with any path information, therefore you simply can't access it. I don't think you want to rely on a feature which is only provided by IE6 and earlier versions. Also, why would your web app need to know about the full path of file to be uploaded back on client's local machine. It would be great to know the use case for the same. I am curious.